# Unable to FTP a file to my server. Looks like a rights issue

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2010

I get this error:
 There were errors during copy web.  Please view log for details.

I try to use both a Visual Studio FTP deployment utility as well as a Command Prompt.

Please check it out:

Here's a [Screencast](http://www.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/690ba86f-993b-4d63-98f3-95c430810dd9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have write access to the FTP site setup in IIS on CHADPC.  Back in the FTP site properties check the write check box - see the screen shot from your web cast.

The sharing tab in Explorer is only for the settings for SMB (Windows) shares, that is \CHADPC\FTPROOT.  You could do you publish using that rather than FTP anyway.

Also you could just create an SMB (Wnidows) share to your WWWROOT directory and publish the web site directly to it's correct location so you don't have to do any copying on CHADPC.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. and thanks for the information. What I really want to do is to deploy by web site to a friend's server. We didn't have much luck getting VPN to work over the internet so I was thinking that FTP might be easier than emailing a large zip file or using a web sharing site like MSN Sky Drive. Is there any issue with FTPing to a website folder? I imagine not. Many thanks for taking the time to view the screen cast.

Comment: No there's no issue FTPing a web site folder.  I was just assuming you could use an SMB share which would be easier.  Also a number of ISP's block users from running FTP servers so using FTP could fail as well.

Comment: What's an SMB share?

Comment: That's another name for a Windows share - that is the remote drives you use like \\SERVER\SHARE.  SMB = Server Management Blocks - the name of the underlying technology.